# get value using DOM HTML

Tags: php, dom

I want to get all the `td` of the ninth `table` element in an HTML page.

**I started with this , but I dont know how to finish it :**

```
define('GLPI_ROOT', '..');
$content = GLPI_ROOT . "/front/yourpage.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);      
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$attbs = $xpath->query("//table td");
foreach($attbs as $a) { 
    print $a->nodeValue;
}
```

**And I have tried this one too, but it didn't work :**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("yourpage.html");
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$table = $tables->item(8);

foreach ($table->childNodes as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {
    echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('".$td->nodeValue."');</script>";
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in yourpage.html, line: 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first one doesn't work because you don't seem to be understanding how XPath works, but your second one is probably a better option.

That said, when has `<td>` ever been a first-level child of `<table>`? You could use `getElementsByTagName` again on the `$table`, that'd work quite well.

Comment: tnks my bro , u said(( use getElementsByTagName again on the $table ))
can you write it ? plz
and what i want is to loop trough every `td` element in the table and get the value

Comment: i'm getting this error : 
**Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in yourpage.html, line: 33**

Comment: That error means your HTML input is invalid. Most likely you have an unescaped `&`.

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: Look at line 33 in `yourpage.html`, you should have a `&` in there that should be `&amp;`

Comment: i have this : `<script type='text/javascript' src='/dailyTickets/plugins/themes/front/getfile.php?theme_id=11&type=js&file=dailyTickets.js'></script>`

Comment: i delete the line , the error is gone , but no data is displayed